# How to return an empty result from php and handle it in typescript

Tags: php, typescript, rest, api

I'm pretty new to web development and I have the following issue:

I make an API call from my typescript like this:

```
let postData = new FormData();
postData.append('action', 'getNextSongs')
postData.append('start', this.result.length)
postData.append('searchTerm', this.searchTerm)

this.data = this.http.post(this.url, postData)
this.data.subscribe(data =>{
  console.log(data);
  this.result = this.result.concat(data);
})
```

And here is the code in the API:

```
 $start = $_POST["start"];
    $searchTerm = $_POST["searchTerm"];
    if(empty($searchTerm))
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM songs ORDER BY nameFromPath ASC LIMIT 30 OFFSET $start";
    }
    else
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM songs WHERE nameFromPath LIKE '%$searchTerm%' OR interpret LIKE '%$searchTerm%' ORDER BY nameFromPath ASC LIMIT 30 OFFSET $start";
    }

$result = $conn->query($sql);

$songs = array();

if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {

    // output data of each row

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        array_push($songs, $row);

        //echo json_encode($row);

    }

} else {

    echo "0 results";

}

echo json_encode($songs);
```

This works fine but if the query returns 0 results (in case the searchterm is does not match anything) the php returns "0 results". If this happens I get the following error in the developer console in chrome:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token r in JSON at position 2 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
text: "0 results[]"
```

My goal is just to handle the zero results in typescript, for example by showing a message 'no more results'.
How can i achieve this?

Comment: This is open to a serious sql injection. Best to use a prepared statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that when you have no results, you first echo `"0 results";` then you also echo `json_encode($songs);`.

When both are used you end up returning a string with both like `0 results[]` which is not a valid JSON string.

Remove the of `echo "0 results";` and just do the `echo json_encode($songs);`

or something like `echo json_encode(['error'=> 'No results found']);` this way you always return a valid JSON string, even if there is an error or just no results.

Something like this should do:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        array_push($songs, $row);
    }

    echo json_encode($songs);

} else {
    echo json_encode(['error'=> 'No results found']);
}
```

Or just this:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        array_push($songs, $row);
    }

} 
echo json_encode($songs);
```

Comment: @DanielRose that means you're still echoing both. Lemme clarify